# Comment "flagged" on opening author profile in a new tab

Tags: bug, comments, flags, election, ipad

I am faced with a very weird behavior with a comment on the moderator election page (reproducible only on Chrome/Safari on iPadOS 16.4). Opening the comment's author profile in a new tab leads to marking the comment as flagged (the flag icon becomes red):

> [image]

This **is not reproducible** with other comments or with the same comment on Android or Windows 11 devices. It looks like only Chrome/Safari on iPadOS is affected.

I can't find how to get the direct link to the comment on election page, but here's the [link to the nominee](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=nomination#post-1510823) that has this comment with interesting behavior.

Comment: The bug happens whenever you tap on certain elements that have the same vertical position as a flag comment icon, such as links in comments, the close dialog, or the flag dialog.

Comment: @Laurel it's weird, but I can't repro that behavior with other comments where user link located on the same line as flag. E.g. (from my gif) the comment written by Nofate, or the last comment by DiMithras. How to explain this?